# Obtener solo el valor de un campo de firestore con vue.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuex, vuejs

Seguramente es muy sencillo de resolver, pero tengo el siguiente problema: necesito el valor de un campo tipo string de nombre 'edad'. Solo he podido llegar a obtener el documento, pero me trae todos los campos en un array, cuando solo necesito uno.

```
getCampo({
      commit
    }) {
      const campos = []
      db.collection('movil').doc('movil').get()
        .then(function(doc) {
          console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
          let movil = doc.data();
          campos.push(movil)

        })
      commit('setCampo', campos)
    }
```

Hasta este punto el código funciona bien, pero cuando ve la consola, me está mostrando todos los campos en un array.

Answer (score 0):

`let movil = doc.data()` por defecto devuelve el contenido de dicho documentos en un objeto, y puedes acceder a los campos de esta forma

```
getCampo({
      commit
    }) {
      const campos = []
      db.collection('movil').doc('movil').get()
        .then(function(doc) {
          console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
          let movil = doc.data();
          campos.push(movil)

        })
      commit('setCampo', campos[0].edad)
    }
```